# react native Jest mock useColorScheme

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, jestjs, mocking

I am trying to mock the useColorScheme hook from react native so I can control what values it returns. My code is below:

```
const mockColorScheme = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Utilities/useColorScheme', () => ({
  useColorScheme: mockColorScheme,
}));

it('Renders correct theme when user selects light', () => {
    const wrapper = ({children}: any) => (
      <ThemeProvider userIsUsingDarkMode={false} userIsUsingSystemTheme={false}>
        {children}
      </ThemeProvider>
    );

    const {result} = renderHook(() => useTheme(), {wrapper});

    expect(result.current.theme).toBeDefined();
    expect(result.current.theme?.text).toStrictEqual('#333');

    mockColorScheme.mockImplementationOnce(() => 'dark');

    expect(result.current.theme).toBeDefined();
    expect(result.current.theme?.text).toStrictEqual('#fbfbfb');
  });
```

I would expect this to work, but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: (0 , _reactNative.useColorScheme) is not a function
```

This comes from my ThemeProvider component:

```
export const ThemeProvider: FunctionComponent<ThemeProviderProps> = ({
  children,
  userIsUsingDarkMode,
  userIsUsingSystemTheme,
}) => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
```

...

```
export const useTheme = () => {
  return useContext(ThemeContext);
};
```

If anyone has any ideas as to how to mock this I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggled for hours to solve the same problem, and I think I found a solution.
All you have to do is to mock actual module for the hook.

```js
const mockedColorScheme = jest.fn()

jest.mock("react-native/Libraries/Utilities/useColorScheme", ()=> ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react-native/Libraries/Utilities/useColorScheme"),
  useColorScheme: mockedColorScheme
}))
it("renders useColorScheme hook with return value of 'dark'", () => {

  mockedColorScheme.mockImplementationOnce(() => "dark")
  const { result } = renderHook(() => mockedColorScheme())


  expect(result.current).toBeDefined()
  expect(result.current).toEqual("dark")
})
```

Answer (score 2):

We could simply mock the module default export.

```js
const mockedUseColorScheme = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Utilities/useColorScheme', () => {
  return {
    default: mockedUseColorScheme,
  };
});
```